# behavior of a program that adds specializations for integral_constant is undefined

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming

I am new to using template metaprogramming in C++.

I want to be able to pass a mixture of ints and typenames to a variadic template. I am not able to specify both, so instead I use `typename... pack`. And then pass an `int N` in as `integral_constant<int, N>`.

However, I noticed in the documentation at https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integral_constant it says

> The behavior of a program that adds specializations for integral_constant is undefined.

But I've also seen code that does this, and even the example code in that same docs does so. So I'm a little confused if I'm misunderstanding what the warning of undefined behavior means. Can I use the above pattern or not? Can anyone elaborate on this?

Comment: Passing an `integral_constant<int,N>` is not  the same as specializing the template. Not at all.

Comment: Ah, I think I didnt understand the word specializaiton properly. So as long as I don't redefine integral_constant<int, N> I should be fine?

Comment: Yes. See this for more details https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization